# Why didn't this Java socket client work?

Tags: java, sockets, java-io

#### The client code

```
try {

    Socket socket = new Socket("localhost", 8888);
    response = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
    request = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());

    //  while (true) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("Enter annual interest rate: ");
    Double rate = input.nextDouble();

    System.out.print("Enter number of years: ");
    int numOfYears = input.nextInt();

    System.out.print("Enter loan amount: ");
    int loanAmount = input.nextInt();

    request.writeObject(new Loan(rate, numOfYears, loanAmount));
    request.flush();

    Loan loan = (Loan)response.readObject();
    double monthlyPayment = loan.getMonthlyPayment();
    double totalPayment = loan.getTotalPayment();
    System.out.println("Total payment: " + totalPayment);
    System.out.println("Monthly payment: " + monthlyPayment);
    //  }
}
catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
catch (IOException ex) {
    System.out.println(ex);
}
finally {
    try {
        response.close();
        request.close();
    }
    catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

#### The server code

```
try {
    ServerSocket ss = new ServerSocket(8888);
    System.out.println("Server started at " + new Date());

    while (true) {
        Socket socket = ss.accept();
        InetAddress ia = socket.getInetAddress();
        System.out.println("Client " + ia.getHostName() + "/" + ia.getHostAddress() + " connected at " + new Date());

        HandleAClient task = new HandleAClient(socket);
        new Thread(task).start();
    }
} catch (IOException ex) {
    System.err.println(ex);
}

class HandleAClient implements Runnable {
    private Socket socket;
    private ObjectInputStream input;
    private ObjectOutputStream output;

    public HandleAClient(Socket socket) {
        this.socket = socket;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            input = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
            output = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());

            while(true) {
                Object object = input.readObject();
                Loan loan = (Loan)object;

                double annualInterestRate = loan.getRate();
                int numOfYears = loan.getNumOfYears();
                int loanAmount = loan.getLoanAmount();

                //  computePayment(annualInterestRate, numOfYears, loanAmount);
                double totalPayment = loanAmount*annualInterestRate/100*numOfYears + loanAmount;
                double monthlyPayment = totalPayment/numOfYears/12;

                loan.setTotalPayment(totalPayment);
                loan.setMonthlyPayment(monthlyPayment);
                output.writeObject(loan);
                output.flush();
            }
        }
        catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (IOException ex) {
            System.err.println(ex);
        }
        finally {
            try {
                input.close();
                output.close();
            }
            catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

#### The output

Server:

```
Server started at Sat Aug 20 18:53:20 CST 2016
Client localhost/127.0.0.1 connected at Sat Aug 20 18:53:29 CST 2016
```

But the client doesn't have any output. What's wrong?

**Finally** I found a solution, I just changed the following code:

```
                Socket socket = new Socket("localhost", 8888);
                request = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
                response = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
```

Then the client works ok:

```
Enter annual interest rate: 4.9
Enter number of years: 10
Enter loan amount: 99
Total payment: 147.51
Monthly payment: 1.22925
Enter annual interest rate:
```

But I don't know why, why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ObjectInputStream reads the header of the stream to check it is an Object Stream. In the client it is waiting for the server to send the header and in the server it is waiting for the client to send the header.

You need to create the output first and flush it so there is a header for the other end to read.